# Purpose of Objective-C bridging header even when Swift is imported to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

The following was the observation made while trying to understand the interoperability with **Swift** and **Objective-C**:

I tried to use **Swift** class in my **Objective-C** project. Xcode asked to create a bridging header and the same was created. I suppose this bridging header is the **Objective-C** bridge header where we write the import statement for the Objective-C class or `framework` which need to be exposed to the swift calls. My plan was to use the swift class within **Objective-C**. Therefore I removed the bridging header along with the Objective-C Bridging Header value form the **Swift** Compiler – Code Generation section of build settings tab. When I build the application the compilation failed with message:

> `/Users/developer/Desktop/workspace/samples/SampleObjectiveC/SampleObjectiveC/AppDelegate.m:23:4:` Receiver type 'NewSwift' for instance message is a forward declaration

NewSwift is my Swift class name which I was using in the Objective-C class.

When I added the bridging header file back and added the **Objective-C** Bridging Header the compilation was successful.

The use of bridging header when trying to expose **Objective-C** api to Swift could be understood.

**But in our case when we are trying to expose Swift class into Objective-C what is the purpose of the Objective-C bridging header?**

**I would like to understand what is actually happening behind the scene?**